# Cross-platform VPN software in a firewalled environment

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, nat

I am currently working on setting up a VPN in order to allow the control over some computers. However there are some problems that I am encountering in setting this up

- Many (if not all) of the computers are in a NAT (non port forwarded) environment
- Some of the computers are in a NAT environment (home network) which does not have port forwarding available
- Some of the computers are behind a company-level firewall (e.g. ports blocked and some websites as well)
- Some computers are among the same LAN
- The computers in this theoretical network would be on different operating systems (Windows and Mac mainly, although there might be Linux as well)

I have already tried using hamachi but it is blocked by the computers mentioned in point 3. (In case you are wondering no, I am not trying to access a company network that disallows VPNs). I also tried using a piece of code called pwnat, but it does not work on windows (under cygwin). Is there a piece of software that could be able to work in this situation?

P.S. I am trying to use something that does not require a port-forwarded server

P.P.S. Security is not of primary concern

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your best and only option may be something like a zero config gateway vpn server at each location.

Using Logmein Hamachi, you can have a small server (even atom based) setup at each of your remote locations.  You would setup the server with as a Gateway Network. This would allow your remote computer to access all of the different resources within that network. Each computer could have REALVNC/Remote Desktop enabled for remote access. The Gateway Network from Logmein Hamachi would basically be just like you were there in that office, plugged into their network.

You can setup and configure each atom gateway server for around $100. You could even go the route of Raspberry Pi machines (http://www.raspberrypi.org/) for $25 a pop.

In short, you'll most likely end up with some sort of zero config VPN client. These often rely on a third party server to accept an initiated request from the clients. This way no port forwarding and/or router configuration needed.

If you are running a private cloud using OpenVZ on some machines, you will have trouble with any/all vpn programs like Hamachi.